# Deleting whole directory before new SW installation

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I created a simple code using Inno Setup and I just want to delete original files inside "SPMPET" directory before installing fresh files and program, automatically. But the code I wrote did not delete the files but kept in there.

```
[Code]
procedure Deleting;
begin
  // Delete the directory C:\Localdata\SPMPET and everything inside it
  DelTree(('C:\Localdata\SPMPET'), True, True, True);
end;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How is the `Deleting` called? Did you try simple `[InstallDelete]` section?

Comment: Yeah, I used like this, but still not working.[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "C:\Localdata\SPMPET"

Comment: *"Still not working"* is not a problem description. What does it do wrong *exactly*? + You didn't answer my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but it's possible that the directory or files inside it are being used by another process, and that's why they can't be deleted. You can try the following steps:

Close all programs that may be using files in the "SPMPET" directory.
Add a try..except block around the DelTree function to catch any exceptions that may be thrown during the deletion process. This will allow you to see any errors that may be occurring.

```
[Code]
procedure Deleting;
begin
try
// Delete the directory C:\Localdata\SPMPET and everything inside it
DelTree('C:\Localdata\SPMPET', True, True, True);
except
MsgBox('Error deleting directory', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
end;

If the directory or files inside it are still not being deleted, probably something else wrong with your code
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. I used your recommended lines in my code, but still the directory is intact and never been deleted, and no message at all. I suspected same thing as there could be a active program running behind, so I restart my PC and did that again, but still the same results.

Comment: You could use process monitor (google it) to watch the setup EXE as it runs and it will show if file deletion is attempted and possibly what failures occur

Comment: Thanks again. The process monitor does not show any apparent activity of deleting any old files and directory. So I looked again the code side. And I noticed that there are green and gray squares on left side of codes. And [Code] has gray square, instead of green. Does this mean anything?